# How to combine input from two records into one output record?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ignition, scada-ignition

I am generating a report which displays how long the plant was running for the day.

Since the operator shuts down the system at lunchtime, I have 2 records for the plant operation hours for each day. I want to display only one record that contains the production Start Time (6:00 am) and production End Time (around 4:00 pm). I have got a table `Runtime_Combined` that has an auto-incrementing index.

I want to select start date (e.g. `9/1/2021 6:04 AM`, which has `runtime_combined_ndx` = 1) and end date (e.g. `9/1/21 4:23 PM`, which has `runtime_combined_ndx` = 2).

```
SELECT ProductionStartDate, ProductionEndDate  
FROM Runtime_Combined     
WHERE month(ProductionStartDate) = month (ProductionStartDate)     
And day(ProductionStartDate) = day( ProductionStartDate)
```

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Please, edit your question and provide sample data, desired output, your current attempt and what is wrong with it. Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `min(start_date)` and `max(end_date)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT date(ProductionStartDate), sum(runtime_combined_ndx)  
FROM Runtime_Combined     
GROUP BY date(ProductionStartDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grouping. Something like:

```
SELECT MIN(ProductionStartDate) AS Start, MAX(ProductionEndDate) As End
FROM Runtime_Combined
WHERE <....>
GROUP BY DATE(ProductionStartDate)
```